# Spring Boot - Cleaning up Tomcat dependencies when creating a non-executable war file

Tags: maven, spring-boot

From the Spring Boot documentation:

> To build a war file that is both executable and deployable into an external container you need to mark the embedded container dependencies as “provided”.

Which looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

However various tomcat packages still remain as dependencies (and thus show up in my `/lib` folder), namely:

1. `tomcat-embed-el` (a dependency of `spring-boot-starter-validation`)
2. `tomcat-jdbc` (a dependency of `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`)

Since I will only ever need to *deploy* my application inside a container and never to run it standalone, how should I proceed with disposing of these dependencies?

P.S. It seems that the first dependency issue is fixed in 1.4.0.M2, see
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5454

Comment: You can exclude `tomcat-jdbc` if you don't need it. Are you sure you don't though? It's a connection pool that's used with JDBC.

Comment: I do make use of jdbc - I just don't see why it should depend on Tomcat (especially since I might be deploying on Jetty) and was wondering if there's a way to safely drop that dependency.

Comment: You could, of course, use an alternative connection pool. `tomcat-jdbc` is somewhat confusingly named. It's a standalone dependency, i.e it doesn't depend on any of Tomcat itself.

Comment: If you add those related dependencies to your _pom.xml_ and mark them as provided they won't be included in the lib folder. I added an answer to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37966575/2823270) I think would apply more or less to this one.