# Executing spring-boot-jar with additional dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

i have developed a service based on spring-boot which maintains a database-connection. It is being packaged to a JAR and is supposed to be delivered as such.
I am, however, not allowed to include database-drivers in this JAR, because customers need to purchase those seperately. Therefore, the JAR does not contain any drivers.

I now tried to build a maven project which executes this JAR via commandline and allows the program to use said drivers. I wanted to add them as dependencies but quickly realised, that that would just add them to the project but not to the executed JAR.

Is there any way to do this with maven? I do not want to change the JAR, i just need the additional dependencies to stay out of it.

Thank you very much in advance,

BFR

Comment: Mark those dependencies with scope `provided`. Then when launching use the -cp to add additional dependencies to the classpath.

Comment: This will solve your problem. Please refer to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37961730/spring-boot-exclude-dependencies-on-packaging)